# XmlSerialiser causing crash upon Deserialization (C#)

Tags: c#, xml-deserialization, gettype

I'm debugging some code which accepts an xml file `@filename` and attempts to deserialize it using the code below:

```
System.Xml.XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(@fileName);
map = new Map();
map = (Map)EuanThoms.Xml.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(reader, map.GetType());
reader.Close();
```

However my application crashes at this point with the error:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at EuanThoms.Xml.XmlSerializer.DeserializeObject(XMLTextReader XMLRead, Type AsType)
at MyApp.MyClass..ctor(String filea, String file2)
at MyApp.MyClass.Main(String[] args)
```

Is this something to do with `map.GetType()` returning NULL? What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Have you debugged it?

Comment: @Kamo The issue I have with that is, the application runs only by opening  an associated file. I'm not sure how I can attach it to the process if as soon as I open the file the application crashes..

Comment: But if you know where it crashes, you can put a breakpoint just before it.

Comment: @Kamo I could but how do I hit that breakpoint if I can't run the application from VS? I can only run it by opening a file and then it crashes.

Comment: So where did you get this source code from?

Comment: @Kamo It was written by a previous employee.

Comment: Do you have access to it?

Comment: @Kamo I have the VS solution and the .exe. The issue is I can't debug it as it won't run on its own without me opening an associated file type, and it crashes as soon as I do.